# User Specific Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Restful web service Application, which has 30+ Api's (services) in it.

I have integrated the Swagger to the application and I could see all the API's in the Swagger UI.

Now, Do we have a way to restrict the user in viewing all the API's in SwaggerUI. For Example, client ABC uses only 5 among 30 API's,client XYX uses 10 API's, now if ABC login to swagger UI he should see only 5 API's not all. Can someone help me in implementing this.

Comment: Hi Ramidi. Generally its a good idea to share your research on what you did to solve the problem and what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve this by adding separate SpringFox Dockets for separate user-groups. For this you have to use path selectors in order to group and expose only the apis that needs to be shown to a particular set of users on a separate swagger-ui login or path.

Please refer:
[SpringFox Config](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#configuring-springfox)

You might have to combine two or three techniques to achieve the goal.

**Cheers and happy coding!**